# How to convert only numbers in a mixed list into float

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to learn Python and i have a problem, so if i have something like that:

```
data_l = ['data', '18.8', '17.9', '0.0']
```

How do i make it like that?

```
data_l = ['data', 18.8, 18.9, 0.0]
```

Comment: You already did. Assign the name to a new list. No?

Comment: Those are integers, not floats.

Comment: y i know, edited

Comment: Will it always be the same format? `[str, float, float, float]`?

Comment: it could be [str, float, float, float] or [str, int, int, float] or [str, float, float, int]

Comment: but always only one string and that string is guaranteed to be the first element?

Comment: yes, the first element is guaranteed to be a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a simple utility function that either converts the given value to a float if possible, or returns it as is:

```
def maybe_float(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return s

orig_list = ['data', '18', '17', '0']
the_list = [maybe_float(v) for v in orig_list]
```

And please don't use names of builtin functions and types such as `list` etc. as variable names.

---

Since your data actually has structure instead of being a truly mixed list of strings and numbers, it seems a 4-tuple of `(str, float, float, float)` is more apt:

```
data_conv = (data_l[0], *(float(v) for v in data_l[1:]))
```

or in older Python versions

```
# You could also just convert each float separately since there are so few
data_conv = tuple([data_l[0]] + [float(v) for v in data_l[1:]])
```

Comment: Note that your additional comments have shown that you had an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where the actual problem is hidden by asking about a "solution". Since your data actually looks more like a tuple of `(str, number, number, number)`, you'd not need this kind of solution as presented in this answer, but just `(data_l[0], *[float(v) for v in data_l[1:]])` (in a recent enough version of Python).

Comment: Yes i apologize, i'll pay attention next time, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `str.isdigit` method and a list comprehension:

```
list = [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in list]
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/K7Z5/0)

Comment: What if they really are floats? e.g. `1.5`

Answer (score 1):

Universal approach:

```
def validate_number(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return s

data = [validate_number(s) for s in data]
```

In case the structure is fixed:

```
data = [s if i == 0 else float(s) for i, s in enumerate(data)]
```

Another one:

```
data = [data[0]] + [float(s) for s in data[1:]]
```

`isdigit` would work in case of positive integers:

```
data = [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in data]
```

Comment: your second version still only works on integers.

edit: your edit was faster than my comment

Comment: that was mine sry

Answer (score 0):

The above-mentioned approaches are working but since a mixed list can also contain an integer value I added an extra checking.

```
def validate(num):
    try:
        return int(num)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        try:
            return float(num)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            return num


vals_ = ['cat' ,'s-3-f','7390.19','12']
new_list = [validate(v) for v in vals_]
```

Output:

```
['cat', 's-3-f', 7390.1, 12]
```