# im trying to sort out a list that ive imported from a file from highest to lowest yet it doesn't seem to sort it

Tags: python, list, file, sorting

this is my code that imports the file, adds it to a list and sorts the list from highest to lowest:

```
for x in range (1):
            scoresList = [ ] #this is a variable for the list
            file = open("Leaderboard file.txt", "r") #this opens the file as a read file
            file_line = file.readlines() #this then reads the lines
            scoresList.append(file_line) #this then appends the lines to the list
            file.close()
            leaderboard_list = sorted(scoresList, reverse=True) #this is supposed to order the numbers yet it doesnt seem to do anything
            print(leaderboard_list)
            start_menu()
```

this is what it prints out:

```
[['\n', "35['jerry'] 20['bill']15['Dan']20['billy']"]]
```

and this is the file it is getting the information from:

```
35['jerry'] 20['bill']15['Dan']20['billy']
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. You are adding the _lines_ from the file to the list, not the numbers or people's names. Parsing those may be a bit more complicated, depending on what you want. Can you add an example of your desired output?

Comment: 35, Jerry. 20, bill. 20, Billy. 15, Dan

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was a bit of a longer walk than I expected.

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        new_text = line.strip().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(" ", "").split("'")[:-1]
        new_text = [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s.title() for s in new_text]
        new_text = [(new_text[i],new_text[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(new_text),2)]
        new_text.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0], reverse=True)

print(new_text)
```

Output:

```
[(35, 'Jerry'), (20, 'Bill'), (20, 'Billy'), (15, 'Dan')]
```

This returns a list (per line) of sorted, capitalized tuples. If your text formatting is critical, you'll have to do some more work from here. LMK if it is critical.

Help from:

[Collect every pair of elements from a list into tuples in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647050/collect-every-pair-of-elements-from-a-list-into-tuples-in-python)

[How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

[Python - How to convert only numbers in a mixed list into float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956711/python-how-to-convert-only-numbers-in-a-mixed-list-into-float)

Comment: it would be helpful if i didnt need to hard code it. the scores and names are in an external file and they need to come from that file..

Comment: Edited to show how to read a file via context manager. You will have to make some changes w.r.t. to how the data is saved, ie printed to screen, saved to another file, etc.