# Setting xlim() removes the xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, line-plot, x-axis, xticks

I am trying to plot 3 lines in matplotlib but whenever I add the xlim([]) the line disappears.

Without xlim:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D 

df.iloc[3:6,5:].T.plot()
```

[image]

with xlim:

```
df.iloc[3:6,5:].T.plot()
plt.xlim([410,1004])
```

[image]

I have made sure that the column I plot are astype float, so what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Well, `plot` clearly sees its input as string.

Comment: @JohanC then why when it has no xlim argument is does plot it? and also I have cganed it to flaot and checked with dypes, it is float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: the labels of the X axis were string.

I have changed them using the following finction from here: [Python - How to convert only numbers in a mixed list into float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956711/python-how-to-convert-only-numbers-in-a-mixed-list-into-float)

```
cols=df.columns.tolist()

def maybe_float(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return s
cols1=[maybe_float(v) for v in cols]
df.columns=cols1
```

After that it worked