# Converting items in list to int with specific condition (Python)

Tags: python, list, integer, conditional-statements

I have a string that consist of characters which all of them divided by comma and I want to create a list with the integers only. I wrote:

```
str = '-4,, 5, 170.5,4,s, k4, 4k, 1.3,  ,, 8'.replace(' ','')
# Now the str without spaces: '-4,,5,170.5,4,s,k4,4k,1.3,,,8'

lst_str = [item for item in str.split(',')
# Now I have a list with the all items: ['-4', '5', '170.5', '4' ,'s', 'k4' ,'4k', '1.3', '8']

int_str = [num for num in lst_str if num.isdigit]
# The problem is with negative character and strings like '4k'
# and 'k4' which I don't want, and my code doesn't work with them.

#I want this: ['-4', '5', '4', '8'] which I can changed after any item to type int.
```

Can someone help me how to do that? Without importing any class.
I didn't find an answer for this specific question (its my first question)

Comment: following EAFP you can write a function that converts `str` to `int` by calling `int` and treating exceptions like `None`s for example and then filter them out

Answer (score 2):

`isdigit()` is a function, not property. It should be called with `()`. It will also won't work on negative numbers, you can remove the minus sign for the check

```
int_str = [num for num in lst_str if num.replace('-', '').isdigit()]
# output: ['-4', '5', '4', '8']
```

If you need to avoid a case of `'-4-'` use number of occurrences parameter

```
num.replace('-', '', 1)
```

Comment: thanks you! this is the best for me right now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def check_int(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
    
int_str = [num for num in lst_str if check_int(num)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it using this:

```
string = '-400,, 5, 170.5,4,s, k4, 4k, 1.3,  ,, 8'.replace(' ','')
# Now the str without spaces: '-4,,5,170.5,4,s,k4,4k,1.3,,,8'

let_str = [item for item in string.split(',')]
# Now I have a list with the all items: ['-4', '5', '170.5', '4' ,'s', 'k4' ,'4k', '1.3', '8']
neg_int = [num for num in let_str if "-" in num]

int_str = [num for num in let_str if num.isdigit()]
neg_int = [num for num in neg_int if num[1:].isdigit()]

for num in neg_int: int_str.append(num)
print(int_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very close to the question [Python - How to convert only numbers in a mixed list into float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956711/python-how-to-convert-only-numbers-in-a-mixed-list-into-float) if you combine it with [python: extract integers from mixed list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725535/python-extract-integers-from-mixed-list).

Your "filter" does not filter at all - the function `num.isdigit` on a non-null string instance named `num` is always true.

Instead of floats you use ints: Create a function that tries to parse something to an int, if not return None.
Only keep those that are not None.

```
text  = '-4,, 5, 170.5,4,s, k4, 4k, 1.3,  ,, 8'    
cleaned = [i.strip() for i in text.split(',') if i.strip()]

def tryParseInt(s):
    """Return integer or None depending on input."""
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None

# create the integers from strings that are integers, remove all others 
numbers = [tryParseInt(i) for i in cleaned if tryParseInt(i) is not None]

print(cleaned)
print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
['-4', '5', '170.5', '4', 's', 'k4', '4k', '1.3', '8']
[-4, 5, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a regex solution:

```
import re

str = '-4,, 5, 170.5,4,s, k4, 4k, 1.3,  ,, 8'
int_str = [num for num in re.split(',\s*', str) if re.match(r'^-?\d+$', num)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace num.isdigit with this function :

```
def isNumber(str):
    try:
        int(str)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Example:`int_str = [num for num in lst_str if isNumber(num)]`